# Is there a CAS for Pharo?

Tags: sympy, smalltalk, symbolic-math, pharo

While learning Python, I found the SymPy module, that is actually a entire computer algebra system (CAS) you can use to solve symbolic problems in mathemathics, like differential equations, polynomials *et cetera*. Now I'm learning Pharo, and I'd like to know if there's a way to do symbolic maths from within Pharo, something similar to SymPy.

Comment: Have you checked PolyMath?

Comment: I read the description. I think it's equivalent to numpy, catering to numeric methods, instead of symbolic methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [CAS in PolyMath](https://github.com/PolyMathOrg/Domains), which is ported from CUIS, and there is [Mathemagics](https://github.com/grpistoia/Mathemagics)