# How to install Domains (port of CUIS Mathematics) in Pharo?

Tags: installation, smalltalk, symbolic-math, pharo

In a past question, [Is there a CAS for Pharo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65270708/14813970), I asked about a Computer Algebra System for Pharo, and people pointed to Domains, a port of Mathematics from CUIS smalltalk, that is part of [PolyMath](https://github.com/PolyMathOrg) project. I suceeded installing PolyMath in Pharo 8, running the following code in the playground, as adviced in https://github.com/PolyMathOrg/PolyMath:

```
Metacello new
        repository: 'github://PolyMathOrg/PolyMath:v1.0.2';
        baseline: 'PolyMath';
        load
```

The problem is, it appears Domains is not installed by default with PolyMath, as I didn't find the corresponding classes in the class browser, and the [Domains subpage](https://github.com/PolyMathOrg/Domains) has no similar instructions on installation.

EDIT (March 2, 2021): I tried to follow the sugestion of EstebanLM, and load from iceberg, having PolyMath installed beforehand. But I only see the following packages in the iceberg screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in a separate github repo (PolyMathOrg/Domains), without a baseline. So you need to just clone the repo from github in Iceberg, and then load the packages in the right order from hand. Iceberg will complain if you try to load a package with unloaded dependencies (Mathematics-Kernel is a good starting point), and you can just reload after loading the missing dependency.

If you note down the needed loading order, you can provide a PR with a baseline

Comment: Thank you. What does PR mean?

Comment: Pull request. But opening an issue with your notes also helps

Comment: The port is atm not complete and behind the Cuis version

Answer (score 1):

Once you load polymath, you will have all packages available to load.
The tool used to load/save packages in Pharo is called iceberg (is a git client). You can find it in the menu "tools" in Pharo 8 or in "browse" in Pharo 9.

Comment: if you double click "PolyMath" you will see the packages.

Comment: Tried it. Domains doesn't show among them.

Comment: in that case, you will have better luck asking in the #polymath channel of pharo discord server, check here for the invite: https://pharo.org/community